# Can we show that if 2 spaces defined with a norm are isomorphic and one of them is Banach, then the other space is also Banach?

Tags: banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis, vector-space-isomorphism

I am asking this because I have a space V= {$p(x)$| $p(x)$=$ax$$^3$, a $\in \mathbb{R}$  } with norm ${\lVert}p(x){\rVert}= \lvert a \rvert $ (i.e the space of all monomials of degree 3) and I've been asked to show that it's Banach. Of course I could use the approach that it follows that every finite dimensional normed space is Banach. I did however want to know that if I could show that if V is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ then V is Banach as $\mathbb{R}$ is Banach.

Comment: Being a Banach space is not a property of the vector space $E$. Is a property of a pair $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $E$, and thus, being a Banach space is a topological statement. Moreover, you can find a vector space $E$ and two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ such that $(E,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is a Banach space and $(E,\|\cdot\|_2)$ isn't. For the sake of completeness, I have to add that in a finite dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent and thus this does not really depend on the norm.

Comment: I just noticed that I left out something. Let me edit the question

Comment: The set of all polynomial with degree exactly $3$ is not even a vector space. What is the zero element? Also your definition is ambiguous. What does $p(x)|ax^3$ means? If you are considering the set of all polynomials of the form $ax^3$, then they are not "all polynomials with degree $3$": where is $x^3 +1$ for example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I left out a lot of information. Let me readjust but I also noticed that the set isn't a vector space.

Comment: With the definition $V=\{aX^3~|~ a \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $\|aX^3\| = |a|$, then the map $aX^3 \in V \mapsto a\in \mathbb{R}$ is a linear isometry that is an isomorphism, and it shows that it is a Banach space if and only if $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!